# Bootstrap 3 Group modal with remote content

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

It might seems that the question has been asked before but not really, I did searched but no luck here or google... not even on bootstrap documentation... 
I have working my dynamic modal with a "remote" content, so here is my code

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="con1.html" data-refresh="true" data-target="#dynamiContent">
        <img src="imgs/pic-1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
    Some title 1
    </a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="con2.html" data-refresh="true" data-target="#dynamiContent">
        <img src="imgs/pic-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
    Some title 2
    </a>
    // My jQuery is
            $('.refresh-me').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#conTenido').modal('refresh');
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
                    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                });
            })
```

So, with that I have my content loaded in to my modal, the info does show correctly, my question is, is there a away that when the user open the first "modal" be able to call the second content, you know like when you use the "FancyBox" for images, you can make image-group and you can surff the images without closing the "pop-up", so I wonder is the same can be done with modal, instead of going one by one...

My modal only has this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dynamiContent">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-con-modal">

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dalog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and the Dynamic content or HTML's only has this

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">The Tittle 1</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="imgs/pic-big-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary refresh-me">Refresh</a>
</div>
```

and that's all there is, every html is the same, this html is loaded into the "dynamiContent" ...

So how do I make a Modal Group?...

Comment: Do you mean something like a [Carousel in a Modal](http://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html)?

Comment: Not exactly, see, one open the modal, you can put any content... so think, cont1.html has images and text and links... and cont2.html has no images at all just text... so when click on "Open Content 1" it will display the content of cont1.html ... so inside the modal will have a button "Next", when click on next it has to load cont2.html ...

Comment: Do you actually want to load some specific variables in your template (like title, description, image), or do you have multiple modal templates and you just want to replace the content of `div.modal-content` ?

Comment: @CyrilDD it has to be very specific, depending on the product/content the user want to see... the modal itself already have a template for this project, but the content is the one that changes everything, each product/content has a different layout and information, some has 5 images on a carrousel, some others just 1, and a few has more than 1 image plus video, audio and download links...